# Confidence interval obtained by Hoeffding's inequality is the "worst-case''?

Tags: statistics, inequality, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

[Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#Confidence_intervals) can be used to generate a confidence interval.

I wonder if Hoeffding-inequality is the "worst-case" approach (among all other common approaches in textbooks, e.g. assuming the sample mean is a normal distribution etc.) in the sense that the confidence interval is the "widest".

My intutive guess is: since the proof of the Hoeffding-inequality doesn't rely on any thing like the central limit theorem, it should be less useful than other approaches with those extra assumptions.

Am I right? Or being naive here..